# Looking for simple yet powerful windows wildcards (`*, ?`) matching implementation

Tags: c#, .net, regex, wildcard

I'm looking for simple and powerful way to implement Windows flavoured `*` and `?` wildcards matching in strings.

`BeginsWith()`, `EndsWith()` too simple to cover all cases, while translating wildcards expressions to regex'es will look to complex and I'm not sure about performance.

A happy medium wanted.

*EDIT:* I'm trying to parse `.gitignore` file and match the same files, as Git does. This means:

- File should be out of repository's index (so I'm checking file's path against one stored in index)
- Number of patterns in `.gitignore` can be large;
- Number of files to check might also be large.

Comment: Very vague. Post some inputs with the desired outputs.

Comment: @Henk, most windows people will know whats meant,   * any number of characters,  ? being just 1 unknown character...  ?blah*.txt  would match any thing with a character before blah, any number of characters after blah and ending in .txt

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'm parsing `.gitignore` file and in my library I need to achieve the same behaviour as original Git offers.

Comment: You can check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188892/glob-pattern-matching-in-net

Comment: @seldon, thanks! It's pretty close to what I'm actually searching for!

Comment: Note that then windows pattern checking on files as a few idiosyncratic legacy features. I don't remember all of them, but some were related to matching the 8.3 name too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalents of the Windows wildcards `?` and `*` in regex are just `.` and `.*`.

---

**[Edit]** Given your new edit (stating that you're looking for *actual files*), I would skip the translation altogether and let .Net do the searching using [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx).

*(note that, for some reason, passing a `?` into `Directory.GetFiles()` matches* "zero or one characters," *whereas in Windows it always matches exactly one character)*

Comment: Personaly, I don't like the idea to translate to regex'es. Because a lot of things need to be translated as well. For example dots, braces, they need to be escaped. And I cannot guarantee that users will be accurate in entering their wildcards. This turns the approach to complex.

Comment: Writing your own pattern matching is certainly more complex than translating to regex.

Comment: @Alexey: See [Regex.Escape()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)

Comment: @BlueRaja: Thanks, it's the way I've looking for!

Comment: @CodesInChaos Not really in this case, check my answer for another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16488364/119561

Answer (score 2):

To get an exact match including all corner-cases, use

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(myPath, myPattern)
```

You may have to create some tempfiles form your targetstrings first.

In other words, I think you should keep your patterns dry until it's time to meet the filesytem.

Comment: It's almost useless for my case, since I'm getting all files in the folder the way you pointed, than I checking how many of them out of Git index. And among files that left I searching for these who don't match set of patterns in the `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

Converting * and ? to regex is quite easy.
For ? replace the "?" with ".{1}"
and for * replace the "*" with ".+?"

That should get you the same behaviour as wildcard matching on windows.

EDIT:
[boolean PathMatchSpec(input, pattern)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773727%28VS.85%29.aspx) will do the job.

```
Private Declare Auto Function PathMatchSpec Lib "shlwapi" (ByVal pszFileParam As String, ByVal pszSpec As String) As Boolean
```

Comment: Yes, it's easy, but is there any other ways not to translate one kind of patterns to another kind?

Comment: You also need to escape characters that have special meaning in regex.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking about different approach.

Comment: Edited answer for PathMatchSpec

Comment: Really cool function! But my library tends to be cross-platform and use pure .NET...

Comment: besides regex or roll-your-own there are no built-in framework functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with regex based approach unless your data volume is humungous or you have data-points to say regex will severely impact performance.

If that is the case, any other solution will also likely affect the performance and you will probably need to hand-roll something.