# Comparing string

Tags: c#, string

Is there any method that allow us to return true if string a likes string b formality?

Exam:

```
 "12:2".Like("*:*") = true
```

or

```
 "what is your name?".Like("*is*name*?")=true
```

Thanks!

Comment: No but you can have a look at regular expressions

Comment: Regex is what you need

Comment: is "*" your only operator here?

Comment: use regex or use VB.NET and it's [`Like`-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to perform Wildcard (\*,?, etc) search on a string using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907720/need-to-perform-wildcard-etc-search-on-a-string-using-regex)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh thanks, I'm not familiar with `vb.net` :)

Comment: thanks @Vajura and everybody,Regex is the solution, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can use this following function using Regular Expression

```
Regex.IsMatch("string", "your expression")
```

Instance following line should return `true`:

```
Regex.IsMatch("12:2", "/[0-9]{2,}:[0-9]{1,}/")
```

> **Note:** This way you have to create exp every time for different format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to check whether a given string matches a DOS like pattern with wildcards (i.e. a pattern that denotes one character with '?' and zero or more characters with '*'):

```
public static bool IsMatch(string str, string pattern)
{
    string regexString = "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace("\\*", ".*").Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(regexString);
    return regex.IsMatch(regexString);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
bool match = IsMatch("what is your name?", "*is*name*?"); // Returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **not-optimized** method. The function may does not take into account some cases, but i think it gives you a point to start from.

Another possible solution is to you Regular Expressions

```
        public static bool Like(string pattern, string str)
        {
            string[] words = pattern.Split('*').Where(w => w.Trim() != string.Empty).ToArray();

            List<int> indeces = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0, l = words.Length; i < l; i++)
            {
                int wordIndex = str.IndexOf(words[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                if (wordIndex == -1)
                    return false;
                else
                    indeces.Add(wordIndex);
            }

            List<int> sortedIndeces = indeces.ToList();
            sortedIndeces.Sort();

            for (int i = 0, l = sortedIndeces.Count; i < l; i++)
            {
                if (sortedIndeces[i] != indeces[i]) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Good Luck