# How to check if a string contains substring with wildcard? like abc*xyz

Tags: c#

When I parse lines in text file, I want to check if a line contains  `abc*xyz`, where `*` is a wildcard. `abc*xyz` is a user input format.

Comment: Very cool, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If asterisk is the only wildcard character that you wish to allow, you could replace all asterisks with `.*?`, and use regular expressions:

```
var filter = "[quick*jumps*lazy dog]";
var parts = filter.Split('*').Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)).ToArray();
var regex = string.Join(".*?", parts);
```

This produces `\[quick.*?jumps.*?lazy\ dog]` regex, suitable for matching inputs.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/4H72WZ)

Comment: To be able to escape the wildcard itself, you can use escaped splitting like here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string_with_escaping#C.23

Answer (score 3):

You can generate `Regex` and match using it

```
 searchPattern = "abc*xyz";

 inputText = "SomeTextAndabc*xyz";
```

---

```
 public bool Contains(string searchPattern,string inputText)
  {
    string regexText = WildcardToRegex(searchPattern);
    Regex regex = new Regex(regexText , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (regex.IsMatch(inputText ))
    {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
 }
```

---

```
public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
    return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern)
                      .Replace(@"\*", ".*")
                      .Replace(@"\?", ".")
               + "$";
}
```

---

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes) is the source
and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907720/need-to-perform-wildcard-etc-search-on-a-string-using-regex) is a similar issue

Comment: Note that you can edit the mehod  WildcardToRegex to control the output regex... 

for example remove the "^" which is used to force the regex to match from the beginning of the input 
or remove the  "$" which does the same but for the end of input

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string prefix = "abc";
            string suffix = "xyz";
            string pattern = string.Format("{0}.*{1}", prefix, suffix);

            string input = "abc123456789xyz";

            bool resutls = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
        }
    }
}
​
```