# How to make program accept glob (wildcards) at command line?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, glob

I would like users to be able to run my program (from Windows cmd) with syntax like this

- `app.exe *.pdf`
- `app.exe February/*.pdf March/*.pdf`
- `app.exe contracts.pdf`

The app would then do its business for each of the relevant files. In Unix this is called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and it's done by the shell.

How can I achieve this for a Windows C# command line app?

Hypothetical syntax

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var file in args.SelectMany(arg => Glob.Expand(arg)))
    {
        Process(file)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing.matcher

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to convert the command line parameter into a regular expression. See [glob pattern matching in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188892/glob-pattern-matching-in-net) for an example on how to convert the command line argument into a regular expression.