# Why wildcard character "*.*" can match a file without extension

Tags: character, match, wildcard

There is a file "a" in a directory. When I search by "*.*", I get "a".
But the file "a" doesn't have a extension and there is no dot in "a". Why?
[image: illustration]

Comment: This isn't a programming question...

Comment: But I also test it using C# and I still get the "a". `string[] res=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\dir", ".");` The sencond parameter "searchPattern" doesn't support regular expressions, as msdn said. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There's an implied `.` in every windows filename.  `a` == `a.`  Because every windows file has an extension, even if that's empty.  You might try `*.+` or `*.+([a-z]|[A-Z])` although I experienced one behavior at cmd prompt, another in UI, and .NET may provide yet another.  You might look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188892/glob-pattern-matching-in-net  and this documentation *might* apply to System.IO  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=vsts